# Why isn't my jquery click function not working but only in safari browser?

Tags: function, animation, safari, click, loading

I want to have a loading icon after button submit is clicked. The code I have works beautifully in all browsers... less in safari. I've already read that click function doesn't work in safari but i'm struggling to find something that works. What can i do differently? Thanks

```
----------CSS------------

#loading {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
position: fixed;
display: block;
opacity: .9;
background-color: #000;
z-index: 99;
text-align: center;
}
#loading-image {
position: absolute;
top: 250px;
z-index: 600;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
#loading-paragraph {
position: absolute;
top: 180px;
z-index: 600;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
color: #f2f2f2;
}

-----------SCRIPT---------------

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#loading').hide();

    $('#button-upload').click(function() {
        $('#loading').show();
    });

});


-----------HTML-------------------

<div id="loading">
            <p id="loading-paragraph">Loading</p>
            <p id="loading-image"><img src="imagens/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..."/></p>
</div>



<form action="" method="POST">
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="button-upload">Send info</button>
</form>
```